# Execute shell script as background process

Tags: php, process, background

Here is my script:

```
<?php echo $_POST['titel'];
echo "<br>send into query.<br>(";
echo $_POST['link'].")";

//$fullcmd="./test.sh ".$_POST['titel']." ".$_POST['link'];

$fullcmd="nohup ./converter.sh ".$_POST['titel']." ".$_POST['link'];

`$fullcmd & >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &`;

?>

<br><a href='converter.php'>Go back to main page (there will be displayed your download)
</a>

</body>

</html>
```

I just want to proceed the php script immediately and don't wait for the return value of `$fullcmd...` 
thought nohup or & or >/dev/null would to it, but nothing worked for me here :(

I'm aware how unsafe such things can be! =) (and how unsafe it is)

Hope you understood problem and you have an answer! =)
(environment: standard lamp server with 777 permission on working folder (for testing))
just to make it clear: the script is executed, but after submitting the form it waits for the complete .sh script to finish, which i would like to work around.

Comment: Do **NOT** use this code. You are opening up your server to a TOTAL remote compromise by allowing malicious users to run ANY command they want on your server. Consider `$_POST['titel'] = '; rm -rf /'`.

Comment: That being said, if you want to run the script as a background process, then `exec('whatever &')`, where the `&` will put it into the background.

Comment: That does not work for me :( exec will not be run